# How to get route_url from page to implement in a form

Tags: python, forms, uri, pyramid, traceback

I am a bit new to building a web framework using `Pyramid` and so far have been doing pretty well. I am currently struggling, however, with what seems to be a simple task. I have a form that allows users to enter information and ratings (via `POST`) so that this information can populate the database I have built using `SQLALCHEMY`.

The form is made up of 4 `db` tables (e.g. user info, category and element ratings, and a feedback textbox). I have built a `view_config` for this `HTML` form using a combination of `request.params['something_to_check']` and a `CRUD` `API` (which compliments a `RESTful` design).

The issue: 
1. I'm trying to grab the id from the assessment page the forms exists on and have it associated with the form (perhaps as a hidden field so I can use `request.params` and use my API (as shown below).

I read on a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229668/python-flask-how-to-get-route-id-from-url) here on stacks of a similar instance, but this function is a single function taking in all the form particulars and not a function designed for matching the id. Pyramid has some good docs on [grabbing resources](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/narr/resources.html#location-aware), but I am uncertain if they are what I am looking for in this instance. How would I implement something similar into my code/form? Also, I am *not* using flask -- I am using JINJA2 templates.

Routes for the form (route entities, assessment, not listed):

```
config.add_route('save_assessment_result', '/save_assessment_result') 
config.add_route('create_assessment_form', '/create_assessment_form')
```

**views.py**

```
@view_config(route_name='save_assessment_result', renderer='templates/assessment_form.jinja2')
def form(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        username = request.params['username']
        firstname = request.params['firstname']
        lastname = request.params['lastname']
        email = request.params['email']
        owner = api.create_user(username, firstname, lastname, email)

        assessment_id = int(request.params['id'])
        assessment_obj = api.retrieve_assessment(assessment_id)
        assessment_results = api.create_assessment_results(owner, assessment_obj)

        category_rating_int = int(request.params['category_rating_int'])
        category = request.params['category_name']
        category_rating = api.create_category_rating(category_rating_int, category, assessment_results)

        element_rating_int = int(request.params['element_rating_int'])
        element = request.params['element_text']
        element_rating = api.create_element_rating(element_rating_int, element, assessment_results)

        text = request.params['text']
        comment = api.create_comment(text, element, assessment_results)

        transaction.commit()
        return {}
```

*form JINJA template*

```
<form method='POST' action='/save_assessment_result' autocomplete="on">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="assessment_id" value='{{assessment_id}}'/> #suppose to find assessment page id
    <dl class='user_form'>
      <dt><label for = 'username'> Username </label></dt>
      <dd>{{ forms.input('username') }}</dd>
      <dt><label for = 'firstname'> Firstname </label></dt>
      <dd>{{ forms.input('firstname') }}</dd>
      <dt><label for = 'lastname'> Lastname </label></dt>
      <dd>{{ forms.input('lastname') }}</dd>
      <dt><label for = 'email'> Email </label></dt>
      <dd>{{ forms.input('email') }}</dd>
      <dd><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></dd>

      # MODE CODE for adding ratings...
    </dl>
```

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? What do you need? The sentence is very long and I tried to parse it, but failed :( The issue: 1. I need to request the route_uri from the assessment page id page the user is putting in their information/ratings so that I can easily plug that into the API to combine both user results and assessment page into an entity; this is called assessment_results which uses user and assessment, e.g. api.create_assessment_results(owner, assessment).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I cleaned it up a bit for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If I read it correctly I would do it like this:

Adding the Route:

```
    config.add_route('success', '/success/{assessment_id}')
```

Then the view:

```
@view_config(route_name='success',   renderer='templates/assessment_form.jinja2')
def form(request, assessment_id):
     with transaction.manager:
        ...
```

Re-POST assessment_id is a hidden field as you are doing.

Getting the route:

```
 url = request.route_url("success", assessment_id=assessment.id)
```

Note: you don't need to use `transanction.manager` as you can automatically wrap all HTTP requests to their own transactions.

- http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-tm/en/latest/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Mikko. The tip on using transaction manager will be investigated. This helped clarify a few things!

Answer (score 0):

The working method to pull the id off a page a user would be working on (via form) is as follows:

- A client visits some form: `http://.../assessment/23.`
- Server matches the route and sends control to `view` code for `/assessment/{id}`.
- `View` code uses `id = int(request.matchdict['id'])` to load
  `assessment_object = api.retrieve_assessment(id)` and populates and
  returns a `dict` as in:

Example:

```
def assessment_form_view(request): 
   #some code
   return {'assessment_id': id, 'video_url': assessment_object.video_url, ...}
```

Jinja renders the form using the template_data via `@view_config(..., renderer='some_template')` on `assessment_form_view`.

Form should show:

```
<form ... action="/save_assessment_result" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="assessment_id" value="{{ assessment_id }}" />
    ...
</form>
```

Client submits this.
Server matches `route` `/save_assessment_result` with `request_method='POST'`, passes control to associated view function `def save_assessment_result_view(request):`

This `view function` (1) pulls all the necessary info out of `request.params`, (2) calls `api.create_user(...)` and `api.create_assessment_result(...)` and (3) `returns` an `HTTP redirect` to some other `route`, `/assessments`.

Great articles that build off of what I have implemented are [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2161680) (discussing

> The request object handled by the view callable will have the
>   parameters of the form stored in an object called params. Getting the
>   form values is much as in other languages that use their Request
>   object to return form values: `firstname = request.params['firstname']` and
>   `lastname = request.params['lastname']`

and [this](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php) (covering hidden code found in a form--as shown above).